# "Hence we request your patience in this regards."

Tags: grammar

I got this quote from a customer service email explaining why my order is being delayed:
...."Hence we request your patience in this regards."...

This reads weird to me, is this a common phrase? Shouldn't the customer service be hoping/asking for my patience instead of "requesting" my patience, since they are causing my delay?

Comment: I'm confused because asking for your patience is the same thing as requesting your patience. So, if you think they should be asking for your patience—they are. (*We request* means *we ask for*. In fact, it's the more polite version. Does that equivalence help or does it not address your confusion?)

Comment: Thanks Jason that definitely helps. I'm not a native English speaker and I've always mixed "request"  with "demand", but since you pointed out it is actually a polite version of "ask" this makes much more sense now.

Comment: *Request* can be used as a more polite form of *demand* too. But it's not just a demand; it's used in both contexts—and in both when you want to be more polite about it. :) (But I can see why using the same word would be confusing.) Consider: *I have a humble request.*

Comment: What's strange is "... this *regards*."

Comment: @Hot Licks - yes. This regard, singular.

Answer (score 0):

> Hence we request your patience in this regard

(it should normally be "regard" singular) means "We ask that you be patient about this issue". The tone here is both formal and old-fashioned, particularly "hence" which means "therefore". Really this phrase means "we are sorry that you must wait".

Answer (score -1):

*Asking* for would be more polite but the difference is minor in my opinion.
There are many such phrases in business letters to explain their lateness or offer to excuse your lateness with a bill, say. The language can slowly become more urgent and less patient with each notice.

If English is their first language it may be that they had not thought long about what words to use for this particular letter.

Comment: No, *asking* is not more polite than *requesting*. On formal wedding invitations, you do not see *We ask for your presence.* Instead, you see *We request your presence.* *Request* is the kind of speech used in polite society, such as royalty. Simply *asking* is more colloquial.